# Can HP-granting armor be moved between wounded troops during deployment phase?

Tags: xenoshyft-onslaught

In XenoShyft Onslaught, after the combat phase ends, surviving troops on a player lane keep their current damage token. Then, on the next deployment phase, the rules states that a player can move equipment between troops on his lane :

> **3. DEPLOYMENT PHASE**
>
> - Once all Troops and Equipment cards have
>     been deployed, each player has one last
>     chance to arrange their Lane as they wish changing
>     the order of Troops (only within
>     their own lane), moving Equipment cards
>     around, etc.

If a trooper with a certain amount of HP, equipped with a HP-granting armor, takes an amount of Damage Token exceeding his base HP but inferior to his total HP (base + armor), can the armor be removed from this trooper and given to another?

If it can be done, what happens then to the trooper? Is he discarded instantly, thus freeing a slot (which can not be done, since troops can not be undeployed from the lane)?